# Already chosen entries in a dropdown menu shows name (Access 2016)

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating an Access application that improves the workflow of our book fair at our school. One of the features is the locker management since that's a part of the school bill.

I have made a dropdown menu with all the lockers and restricted it. I placed an index on it and disallowed duplicates.

Now, is it possible to hide the already chosen options? For example, if locker A001 has been chosen, that when you go to the next student, you are unable to even SEE the locker A001, because it has been selected already? Or alternativally, that the name of the student that already chose that locker is shown.

EDIT: Yes, I could ask the sql code but I would also love to know how to implement this in Access.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query: list all items in one table that do not appear in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048709/sql-query-list-all-items-in-one-table-that-do-not-appear-in-another-table)

Comment: The suggested answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048709/sql-query-list-all-items-in-one-table-that-do-not-appear-in-another-table doesn't answer this question. Since it's the other way around in that question.

Comment: Did you look at the other answers, such as the one with 3 upvotes? The point is, you need to use both tables - table of all lockers and table of assigned lockers - to determine what is still available and exclude those that are assigned. Edit question to show sample data. Then you also need code to require the combobox for each record. Be aware a conditional (or cascading) combobox will not work nicely on continuous or datasheet form if the combobox has lookup alias.